recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while proxying upgraded connection in nginx
We have a printing application running behind an nginx, and since moving to a new proxy server with a newer nginx, customers are intermittently reporting
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
   at Domain.Printing.Service.Library.SignalRClient.Execute()

and
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

which I believe are connected to these messages in the application and nginx logfiles:
Application log:
2024-06-17 08:58:08 10.24.11.16 POST /printing/SignalR/signalr/abort clientProtocol=2.1&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22IntegratedPrintingHub%22%7D]&connectionToken=mLUYvm 80 - 10.24.11.15 SignalR.Client.NetStandard/2.4.1.0+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.2.9200.0) - 200 0 0 0

Nginx error log:
2024/06/17 08:58:08 [error] 892#892: *3890934 recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while proxying upgraded connection, client: 66.66.66.66, server: printing.domain.info, request: "GET /printing/SignalR/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=2.1&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22IntegratedPrintingHub%22%7D]&connectionToken=mLUYvm HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.24.11.16:80/printing/SignalR/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=2.1&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[%7B%22Name%22:%22IntegratedPrintingHub%22%7D]&connectionToken=mLUYvm", host: "printing.domain.info"

nginx -T:
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.info:38
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.info:38
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.2" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.info:38
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "TLSv1.3" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.info:38
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 7680;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}



# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.info:
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

log_format lglog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name $host to: $upstream_addr: $request $status upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

upstream printingbackend2 {
  server ltweb05.domain.local max_fails=3 fail_timeout=10s;
}

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:@SECLEVEL=0";

ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.info.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.info.key;
#ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;

# cache-buffers
proxy_buffering   on;
proxy_cache_valid any 10m;
proxy_cache_path  /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=lg-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path   /var/cache/nginx/tmp;
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers     100 8k;
client_max_body_size 100M;

server {
  listen              80;
  listen              443 ssl;
  server_name         printing.domain.info;
  proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header    X-Proto           $scheme;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  add_header          via "domain proxy ($proxy_host, $upstream_addr)";
  client_header_timeout 45m;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/printing.domain.info-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/printing.domain.info-error.log;
  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://printingbackend2;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    #http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
    #proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
    #proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_buffering     off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    client_body_timeout 45m;
    proxy_read_timeout  45m;
  }
}

I've change the timeouts, altered the proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade; line and added the proxy_ssl_server_name on; . Still getting the 104: Unknown error. Still can't understand why it looks like the application returns a 200 OK, but nginx sees an error. Any ideas?

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name printing.domain.info;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.info.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.info.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:@SECLEVEL=0";

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://printingbackend2;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 60m;
        proxy_send_timeout 60m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 60m;

        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/printing.domain.info-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/printing.domain.info-error.log;
}


Thanks for the suggestions, but sadly, it didn't help.
